# is cx-freeze incompatible with python for .net?

Tags: python, .net, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, python.net

for sake of testing I am using demo from https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/demo/wordpad.py to convert it to .exe using cx_freeze==5.0.

but it shows missing clr modules (obviosly).
How to work around with this?

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "WordPad",
    version = "3.1",
    description = "A word pad demo",
    executables = [Executable("main.pyw", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

Disclaimer: This is my first attempt using cx_freeze.

Comment: you need to add clr.pyd and python.runtime.dll to additional files to include during freezing, see pyinstaller: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1801

Comment: Will this also aply to cx-freez?

Comment: for cxfreeze follow these instructions: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#problems-with-running-frozen-programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This auto-discovery of pythonnet was merged to cx_freeze:

https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/pull/251